# Get segment properties in amcharts gantt by doubleclicking

Tags: amcharts

I want to set a hidden ID for each segment in an am-charts gantt chart. So when the user double clicks a segment i want to retrieve data using that ID and show in a popup window.

```
"dataProvider": [ {
    "category": "John",
    "segments": [ {
        "start": "2018-01-01",
        "end": "2018-01-10",
        "color": "#f00",
        "task": "Task #1",
        "key": "1000"
    }, {
        "start": "2018-01-12",
        "end": "2018-01-20",
        "color": "#00f",
        "task": "Task #2",
        "key": "1001"
    }, {
        "start": "2018-01-25",
        "end": "2018-02-10",
        "color": "33800F",
        "task": "Task #3",
        "key": "1002"
    } ]
} ]
```

[image]
I am able to get the Category value but don't know how to get Segments values.

Any example would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `clickGraphItem` for your double-click functionality, you can access the segment information through the graph's [`segmentData`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#segmentData) property in the event object:

```
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "clickGraphItem",
    "method": function(e) {
      alert(e.graph.segmentData.key)
    }
  }]
```

Demo below:

```js
AmCharts.useUTC = true;
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "gantt",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "period": "hh",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "balloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN",
  "columnWidth": 0.5,
  "valueAxis": {
    "type": "date",
    "minimum": 7,
    "maximum": 31
  },
  "brightnessStep": 10,
  "graph": {
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "balloonText": "<b>[[task]]</b>: [[open]] [[value]]"
  },
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryField": "category",
  "segmentsField": "segments",
  "colorField": "color",
  "startDate": "2015-01-01",
  "startField": "start",
  "endField": "end",
  "durationField": "duration",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "category": "John",
    "segments": [{
      "start": 7,
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#46615e",
      "task": "Task #1",
      "key": "1001"
    }, {
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#727d6f",
      "task": "Task #2",
      "key": "1002"
    }, {
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#8dc49f",
      "task": "Task #3",
      "key": "1003"
    }]
  }, {
    "category": "Smith",
    "segments": [{
      "start": 10,
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#727d6f",
      "task": "Task #2",
      "key": "1004"
    }, {
      "duration": 1,
      "color": "#8dc49f",
      "task": "Task #3",
      "key": "1005"
    }, {
      "duration": 4,
      "color": "#46615e",
      "task": "Task #1",
      "key": "1006"
    }]
  }, {
    "category": "Ben",
    "segments": [{
      "start": 12,
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#727d6f",
      "task": "Task #2",
      "key": "1007"
    }, {
      "start": 16,
      "duration": 2,
      "color": "#FFE4C4",
      "task": "Task #4",
      "key": "1008"
    }]
  }],
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "clickGraphItem",
    "method": function(e) {
      alert("key: " + e.graph.segmentData.key)
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gantt.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```